# Insert image (in the same folder as the notebook) in a text cell of the notebook with Colaboratory

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory, jupyter-lab

I work on a notebook with Colaboratory and I try to insert a picture, stored in the same folder as the notebook, in a text cell.

I've tried : `![](image.png)` and `<img src="image.png" />`

Even `![](./image.png)` and `<img src="./image.png" />`

But It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a relative path but that's not how colab markdown cells work.
Inline images can only reference publicly-readable (absolute) URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hack to do that

```py
path = '/usr/local/share/jupyter/nbextensions/google.colab'
!cp -r {path}/* .
!rm -r {path}
!ln -s /content {path}
# change base tag
from google.colab.output import eval_js
def change_base_url():
  eval_js("""
  var base = document.createElement('base')
  base.href = 'https://localhost:8080/nbextensions/google.colab/'
  document.head.prepend(base)
  """)
# make it run automatically in every cell
get_ipython().events.register('pre_run_cell', change_base_url)
```

It merges the `google.colab` directory with `/content`. Then change the base path of output frame to `/nbextensions/google.colab`

Here's an example notebook

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AX30RdTRNdrhu6qDZd-5ptlsgnTSTFAu